# Update a cell based on availability of a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a metadata (`column_struct`) table containing `column_name`,`table_name`and `data_type` values. There is also a `flag` field.

```
columnname  tablename   datatype   flag
------------------------------------------
desc1       sec         varchar     null
date        sec         datetime    null
sype_id     sec         int         null
s_type      sec         varchar     null
date        prod        datetime    null
```

I need to check if each column is present in the corresponding tables (`sec,prod`) in another server (linked) and set the `flag` value to `1` if it is present and 0 otherwise. I am confused as to how i should go forward. I used the following query and it updates all the `flag` values if a column is not found.

```
update A
set Flag=1
  from [metadata].[column_struct] A 
  where not exists( select C.name,B.name from
  [linked_server].db_name.sys.objects B
  join [linked_server].db_name.sys.columns C 
      on  B.object_id=C.object_id
  join [linked_server].db_name.sys.types D 
      on D.user_type_id=C.user_type_id
where A.tablename  =B.Name 
and A.columnname=C.name
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working with a query that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (tablename VARCHAR(50), columnname VARCHAR(50), flag INT);
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'account', 'account_status', NULL;
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'account', 'account_not_there', NULL;

UPDATE
    t
SET
    flag = CASE WHEN sc.[name] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
    #temp t
    LEFT JOIN linked_Server.remote_db_name.sys.tables st ON st.[name] = t.tablename
    LEFT JOIN linked_Server.remote_db_name.sys.columns sc ON sc.[object_id] = st.[object_id] AND sc.[name] = t.columnname;

SELECT * FROM #temp;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

When I replace linked_server and remote_db_name with values that work in my environment I got results as follows:

```
tablename   columnname          flag
account     account_status      1
account     account_not_there   0
```

...which is correct.

This isn't a million miles from your query, but you are using `NOT EXISTS` in a way that doesn't seem to make any sense to me?

Comment: Thanks. This helps. :)